# How can I listen to events emitted by another object in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want something like this:

```
var eventSource = new EventEmiiter();

var eventListener = new EventEmitter();

eventSource.emit("MyEvent", data);

eventListener.on("MyEvent", function(data) {
    console.log("captured an event");
});
```

I have read some articles introducing EventEmitter, and all of them make a example with exactly one EventEmitter instance doing both `emit` and `on`. I wonder whether it is the best way or not? Can I realize the event system as I did above? And how?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this: if you know there is a singer doing opera in your town's concert hall, you can hear it by going there and listening to the singer; you can't hear it at home by listening to your (disconnected) earphones. There are specific objects that will transmit things for you, which observe the target emitter and emit (relay, proxy) their events on themselves, like a radio transmission system: listening to the radio, you get to hear the singer.

You can move the metaphor into EventEmitter world pretty much perfectly.

The main question is, really, why you need this architecture, as opposed to listening to the emitter directly.

Comment: maybe he's looking for something like an EventAggregator. I think that's the actual question here. A publish and subscribe mechanism to support loose coupling of his modules .

Comment: @eranotzap: There are certainly valid reasons for event proxies, but the exact solution should depend on the exact need; the question is a bit too vague for me to give any "this is the correct way" answers.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question as OP want to decouple the Emitter and Listener module. So, I would like to share practice which i usually follow to achieve same.

**EventManager**

```
var PingPongListener = require('./listener');
var PingPongEmitter = require('./emiiter');
var pingPongEventListener = [];

var Manager = function(){
    this.emitter = new PingPongEmitter();
    this.emitter.on('pingpong', function(msg){
        pingPongEventListener.forEach(function(listener, index){
            listener.onPingPong(msg);
        });
    })
};

Manager.prototype.register = function(listener, event){
    if(event=='pingpong'){
        pingPongEventListener.push(listener);
    }else{
        console.log('Cant register listener. No such event', event);
    }
};

(function(){
    var tom = new Manager();
    var danny = new PingPongListener('Danny');
    var shawn = new PingPongListener('shawn');
    tom.register(danny, 'pingpong');
    tom.register(shawn, 'pingpong');
})();
```

**Emiiter.js**

```
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

var PingPong = function(){
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function(){
        self.emit("pingpong", 'hello');
    }, 2000);
};


util.inherits(PingPong, EventEmitter);

module.exports = PingPong;
```

**Listener.js**

```
var PingPongListener = function(name){
    this.name = name;
};
PingPongListener.prototype.onPingPong = function(msg){
    console.log(msg + ' ' + this.name);
};
module.exports = PingPongListener;
```

Basic idea is to add an interface(EventManager) between Emitter and Listener, this allows me to control the communication between listener. EventManager typically has EventPolicies which must be satisfied by Listener in order to subscribe the event.

**Note**

Any improvement in this idea is welcome.

Comment: Maybe I was thinking in the wrong way that there is a global event hub to which EventEmitter will emit an event so that another EventEmitter can receive that message, kind of like subscribe-publish system. But obviously, EventEmitter is not designed that way naturally, just like in your practice, emit and on are still invoked by one EventEmitter. Anyway, thanks for your help!